# Problem Concerning The Euclidean Algorithm For Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(x) = x^3-x^2-x-2$ and $Q(x) = 2x^2-3x-2$

What do I do in the first step when The coefficient in front of $2x^2$ is greater than the coefficient in front of $x^3$  ($2>1$)

In the first step do I simply write $x^3 = \dfrac{1}{2}2x^2\times x$ And do I continue with non-whole coefficients?

Or is therea way to always have whole coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring of polynomials with integer coefficients, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, is not an Euclidean domain, which means that the Euclidean division algorithm is not available in it. But since the ring of polynomials with *rational* coefficients is Euclidean, we can actually divide if we allow for rational coefficients. For example, if you divide $X^2$ by $2X$ you necessarily get $\frac12 X$.

A related, but different question, is if given two polynomials with integer coefficients there always exists a greatest common divisor for them, and the answer is yes. For the previous example we have $\gcd(X^2,2X)=X$.

Comment: So If I am in the $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ I can have non-whole coefficients?!

Comment: @aribaldi Yes, that's it: $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ means polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, which by definition is the set of rational numbers, i.e., fractions of the form $p/q$ with $p,q$ integers and $q\neq 0$, which are not whole numbers.